# Set new id using name to input javascript

Tags: javascript, input, setattribute

I have input type text

```
<input type="text" name="processName">
```

I want to set new id to this input element using name of the input element

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("processName")[0].setAttribute("id", "proceesOffsetId");
```

Which is not working

Comment: Why? What would you use the ID for? You'd have to select the element by name first, and at that point an ID would be redundant. Anyway, a hint: `.getElementsByTagName("processName")` is looking for `<processName>` elements...

Comment: i want to focus the cursor..  can i do like this - `document.getElementsByTagName("processName")[0].focus()`

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` is the wrong method. Try `.getElementsByName()`. Or `document.querySelector('[name="processName"]').focus()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `getElementsByTagName` refers to the element tag (for example: div tag, li tag, input tag, etc...). It doesn't fetch elements via the `name` attribute.

So in your case, to target that `input` element, you could do something like this:

`document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].setAttribute("id", "proceesOffsetId");`

This will give the `input` element an `id` of `proceesOffsetId`.

Alternatively, to target the `name` attribute, you could use `document.getElementsByName`:

`document.getElementsByName("processName")[0].setAttribute("id", "proceesOffsetId");`

This will also give the `input` element an `id` of `proceesOffsetId`.

Answer (score 3):

you should use [`getElementsByName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

```
 document.getElementsByName("processName")[0].id = "proceesOffsetId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getElementsByTagName, use getElementsByName which is appropriate as per your requiement.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" name="processName">
```

JS:

```
var x= document.getElementsByName("processName");
console.log(x);
x[0].setAttribute("id", "proceesOffsetId");
```

Here's the reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp